# Live SDK Calendar Event Upload

Tags: c#, calendar, windows-phone, live

is it possible to upload a list of events with the Microsoft Live SDK for Windows Phone, rather than each one individually?

My current code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime?, Klassenbibliothek.TagNeu> Element in KalenderJahr)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> calEvent = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    calEvent.Add("name", Element.Value.Name);
    calEvent.Add("description", Element.Value.Name);
    calEvent.Add("start_time", Element.Value.Starttime);
    calEvent.Add("end_time", Element.Value.Endtime);
    calEvent.Add("location", "");
    calEvent.Add("is_all_day_event", true);
    calEvent.Add("availability", "busy");
    calEvent.Add("visibility", "private");
    client.PostAsync(CalID + "/events", calEvent);
}
```

thanks Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

But Live SDK allows you to write on the calendar connected, not user?

You can log the user on the same account on the phone and writing in his calendar. 
The changes will be reflected in the phone.

Otherwiser... Should do one by one :

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime?, Klassenbibliothek.TagNeu> Element in KalenderJahr) {
    Dictionary<string, object> calEvent = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    new SaveAppointmentTask {
        StartTime = Element.Value.Starttime,
        EndTime = Element.Value.Endtime,
        Subject = Element.Value.Name,
        Location = "",
        Details = "",
        IsAllDayEvent = ""
    }.Show();
}
```